# Any suggestions to why the </option> tag does not get printed at end of second echo?

Tags: php, html, mysql

The second echo statement prints without the closing `</option>` tag. But prints the rest of the code correctly. if i inspect the HTML the text Any Publisher... is left in ' ' single quotes. Thanks

```
 function getPublishers (){

    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT publisher FROM book ORDER BY publisher ASC";
    $rs = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    $rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs);
    $tot_rows = mysql_num_rows($rs);
    if($tot_rows>0){
        echo "<select name=\"srch_publisher\" id=\"srch_publisher\>\n";
        **echo "<option value\"\">Any Publisher&hellip;*</option>*\n";**
        do{
            echo "<option value=\"".$rows['publisher']."\">".$rows['publisher']."</option>";
        } while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs));
        echo "</select>";
    }
    mysql_free_result($rs);
}
```

Comment: Could be the missing double quote `"` at the end of `srch_publisher` -> `id=\"srch_publisher\>\n"` or the missing `=` for `value` -> `<option value\"\">`. These will create invalid syntax.

Comment: Close id=\"srch_publisher\" MISSING an " at the end !! 
AND Try this way:
echo '<option value="">Any Publisher&hellip;*</option>*\n';

Comment: @Sean Good man, great help it was the " after id=\"srch_publisher\>\n"

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a closing quote sign after the `id="srch_publisher"`:

```
echo "<select name=\"srch_publisher\" id=\"srch_publisher\>\n";
                                                         ↑
                                  missing closing quote (") at this position
```